# Does @media max-width rule applies to printing?

Tags: css, printing, media-queries

I have a set of general styling followed by some styles within the `@media` `max-width` rules and finally the style to apply for printing:

```
/* general */

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
....
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
....
}

@media print {
...
}
```

How does CSS apply those rules when it comes to printing. I tried printing with Chrome, apparently, some rules within those `max-width` rules are applied as well. For an A4-size paper (210mm in width), how does the `max-width` rule apply?

Comment: `max-width` does apply in `print` media. You can always find these things in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, it is unclear on the treatment when virtual dimensions like `px` is used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like these instead of yours:

```
media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
 //styles go here
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 //styles go here
}

@media print {
 //styles go here
}
```

Comment: Ah.. i see... can just exclude print?

Comment: Yes, You can use as you want. If you want you can use `@media print` and if not, don't use.